# Criar uma trigger que seja executada sempre que um produto for deletado

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, trigger

Como criar uma *trigger* que seja executada sempre que um produto for deletado, executando a ação de deletar em todos os lotes relacionados com o produto deletado.

Segue aí meu código SQL:

```
create database provafinal;

use provafinal;




create table produto
(codProduto integer not null,
 nomeProduto varchar(50) not null,
 marca varchar(50) not null,
 precoCusto decimal(15,2) not null,
 precoVenda decimal(15,2) not null,
 primary key (codProduto)); 

 create table loteproduto
 (codProduto integer not null,
  codLote integer not null,
  nuLote char(10) not null,
  dtValidade date,
  primary key (codProduto, codLote),
  foreign key (codProduto) references produto(codProduto));
insert into produto (codProduto, nomeProduto, Marca, precoCusto, precoVenda) 
values (1, 'Inseticida 500 ML', 'SBP',4,7);
insert into produto (codProduto, nomeProduto, Marca, precoCusto, precoVenda) 
values (2, 'Pastilha refil', 'SBP', 2,4);
insert into produto (codProduto, nomeProduto, Marca, precoCusto, precoVenda) 
values (3, 'Refrigerante guaranÃ¡', 'Pureza', 3,5);
insert into produto (codProduto, nomeProduto, Marca, precoCusto, precoVenda) 
values (4, 'Refrigerante laranja', 'Pureza', 3,5);
insert into produto (codProduto, nomeProduto, Marca, precoCusto, precoVenda) 
values (5, 'Amaciante amarelo', 'Downy', 6,9);
insert into produto (codProduto, nomeProduto, Marca, precoCusto, precoVenda) 
values (6, 'Amaciante rosa', 'Downy', 4,5);
insert into produto (codProduto, nomeProduto, Marca, precoCusto, precoVenda) 
values (7, 'Frango', 'Sadia', 5,10);
insert into produto (codProduto, nomeProduto, Marca, precoCusto, precoVenda) 
values (8, 'Peru', 'Sadia', 5,10);



insert into loteproduto (codProduto, codLote, nuLote, dtValidade) 
values (1, 1, '399A',null);
insert into loteproduto (codProduto, codLote, nuLote, dtValidade) 
values (1, 2, '323A','2012-12-31');
insert into loteproduto (codProduto, codLote, nuLote, dtValidade) 
values (2, 1, 'EF2A','2012-12-30');
insert into loteproduto (codProduto, codLote, nuLote, dtValidade) 
values (7, 1, 'EF3A',null);
```

Comment: `ON DELETE CASCADE` não serve para o seu caso?

Comment: Olá cara tudo bom?Esse metodo até pode servir, só que eu pretendo usar triggers para esse meu exemplo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A ação referencial `ON DELETE CASCADE` serve para o seu caso, sem haver necessidade de criação de uma trigger. Quando deletamos um registro na tabela `produto`, queremos que os registros na tabela `loteproduto`, que se associam ao registro de produto deletado, sejam removidos também. Por exemplo, quando deletamos um registro de código no. 2 com a seguinte query:

```
DELETE FROM produto WHERE codProduto = 2;
```

Queremos que os registros associados a tal produto na tabela `loteproduto` sejam deletados também. Para tanto, isso pode ser feito na criação da tabela:

```
CREATE TABLE loteproduto (
    ...
    CONSTRAINT fk_loteproduto_produto
    FOREIGN KEY (codProduto)
        REFERENCES produto (codProduto)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

Ou alterando a tabela:

```
ALTER TABLE loteproduto
    ADD FOREIGN KEY (codProduto)
        REFERENCES produto (codProduto)
    ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

Se você realmente prefere utilizar triggers, é só utilizar o seguinte código:

```
CREATE TRIGGER produto_on_delete AFTER DELETE ON produto
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
DELETE FROM loteproduto
       WHERE loteproduto.codProduto = old.codProduto;
END
```

## Referência

[MySQL ON DELETE CASCADE Deletes Data From Multiple Tables](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-on-delete-cascade/)

Comment: Muito obrigado meu caro!Era isso que eu procurava!God bless you

Comment: Cara uma ultima duvida, quando eu vou deletar um produto pelo código aparace o erro 1451: cannot delete or update a parent row                                                 Foi isso que eu utilizei para deletar:                         DELETE FROM produto 
WHERE codProduto=1;

Answer (score 1):

Aqui esta a [especificação](http://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/triggers/before_delete.php) da criação da trigger que você deseja.

Este é basicamente o código da trigger:

```
DELIMITER //
    CREATE TRIGGER minhaTrigger
    BEFORE DELETE ON minhaTabela FOR EACH ROW

    BEGIN
       --Seu código para deletar na Minha_Segunda_Tabela
    END; //
DELIMITER ;
```

Aconselho dar uma estudada em como utilizar a trigger. Da uma olhada [neste site](http://www.linhadecodigo.com.br/artigo/3567/mysql-basico-triggers.aspx).

Particularmente, eu não faria uma Trigger para isso. Existe a clausula `ON DELETE CASCADE` na criação de Chaves Estrangeiras que quando uma linha na tabela é excluída, o banco automaticamente deleta suas dependências.

Dê uma olhada na [documentação](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html) da criação de chaves estrangeiras do Mysql.

Comment: Obrigado cara! vai ajudar!

Answer (score 0):

Boa tarde.

Primeiramente você deverá verificar se deve ser executado antes ou depois de deletar.
Verifique este link, poderá lhe ajudar:
[Introdução a Triggers](http://www.linhadecodigo.com.br/artigo/3567/mysql-basico-triggers.aspx)

Abraços.